# How to Extract data from hstore json array in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, hstore, metabase

I have a database table which has a column having data stored in a format similar to store json array. To help make things clear, let's say the table is called browser having two columns -> id and json_data.

```
| ID| _________________________________________ json_date __________________________________________________________________________________________________________. |
| --|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1 | [{"key"=>"userAgent", "value"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"}, {"key"=>"webdriver", "value"=>"not available"}, {"key"=>"language", "value"=>"en"}, {"key"=>"colorDepth", "value"=>24}, {"key"=>"deviceMemory", "value"=>8}, {"key"=>"hardwareConcurrency1234d", "value"=>4}]  |
|---|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| 2 | [{"key"=>"userAgent", "value"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.98 Safari/537.39"}, {"key"=>"webdriver", "value"=>"not available"}, {"key"=>"language", "value"=>"en"}, {"key"=>"colorDepth", "value"=>24}, {"key"=>"deviceMemory", "value"=>16}, {"key"=>"hardwareConcurrency1234d", "value"=>4}] |
|---|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
```

In this data, I want to extract the json/hstore value where the key is 'deviceMemory'. I am using PostgreSQL in Metabase. I've tried to use json_array_elements and hstore_to_json functions but haven't been able to resolve this.
Could someone help me out in this?

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is the data type of that column?

Comment: The format is all the worst parts of an array and hash. It's going to make it slower and more difficult to retrieve values. If you can change it, it would be much simpler as `{"userAgent" => "Mozilla/5.0 ...", "webdriver" => "not available", ...}`